# How to save user or session data in FormView along with form data?

Tags: django, session, authentication, formview

I am trying to develop a small app a user can upload images after logging in. I have used `ModelForm` to generate the form for uploading the image and its decription. The `ArtWork` model has foreign key relationship with the `User` model. I exclude the `user` field from the ModelForm. Now I do not have any clue how to save the logged in user along with the form data into the database. Thanks in advance.

Here is my `ArtWork` Model

```
class Artwork(models.Model):

    art_image = models.ImageField("Art Image", upload_to="images", blank=True,null=True)
    art_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.art_name
```

Here is my View

```
class UploadArtworkView(FormView):
    form_class = ArtworkForm
    success_url = "/"
    template_name = "artwork/upload.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #artwork = Artwork(art_image= self.get_form_kwargs().get('files')['art_image'])
        #print "Art name is" + form.post['art_name']

        form.save()
        print self.request.user.name
        return super(UploadArtworkView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Here is the Form

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Artwork


class ArtworkForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Artwork
        fields = ['art_image','art_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is very similar to [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) in the Django docs. You have already realised that `form_valid` is the correct method to override, so you are very close to the answer. The trick is to access the object using `self.form.instance`, and set the user:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(UploadArtworkView,self).form_valid(form)
```